# How to use a specific port for ftp over tls filezilla

Tags: ftp, ftps

I want to configure filezilla to use port 2121 with FTP over TLS and standard port 21 for plain FTP?

How can do that? I have configured FTP over TLS with certificates, but clients can still connect to ftp server using both ftp and ftpes.

Comment: You need the passive mode port set correctly to be used. Check @David answer there http://serverfault.com/questions/10807/what-firewall-ports-do-i-need-to-open-when-using-ftps

Comment: Why do you want to use a different port for FTP and FTPES?

Answer (score 1):

The FileZilla Server cannot use different ports for plain FTP and explicit FTPS (ftpes).

It would not even make much sense.